# Getting Boost.Spirit to handle optional elements

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have an AST element defined roughly as

```
struct Something
{
  boost::optional<string> foo;
  string bar;
}
```

in my parsing code, I parse it as

```
-(identifier >> ':')
>> type
```

Now, here's the problem: if I feed the parser the string `hello:world`, everything works correctly, i.e.,

```
foo = hello
bar = world
```

If, however, I feed the parser the string `hello`, I get

```
foo = hello
bar = hello
```

whereas what I want is

```
foo = boost::optional<string>()
bar = hello
```

How can I achieve this in Boost.Spirit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361571/boost-spirit-parsing-optional-prefix

Comment: @llonesmiz thanks, this fixed things!