# In Boost.Spirit, why is a fusion wrapper required for a vector (wrapped in a struct), but not a variant?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I would like to understand the exact scenarios in which `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` is required when encapsulating `struct`s using Boost.Spirit.

What follows are two examples.  One example is a single-member `struct` with (only) a `variant` data member.  This version does NOT require the `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` macro that wraps the struct in a Fusion container.  A constructor is sufficient for Spirit to instantiate/populate the attribute based on the incoming rhs.

(Please see comments in the code for my understanding of the attribute type I think is being generated by Boost.Spirit for the rhs of the rule definitions due to the attribute collapsing rules.)

The second example is a single-memeber `struct` with (only) a `vector` data member.  Even with the constructor defined to allow Spirit to populate the attribute based on the rhs, it fails to compile without `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`.

**Why the difference?**  I'd like to understand why, in the first scenario, a constructor can be used to populate the attribute (the `struct`), whereas in the second scenario, a constructor is not sufficient and `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` must be used.

---

Examples noted above follow.

**EXAMPLE 1: Variant**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

using intermediate = boost::variant<std::string, int>;

// Simple parser demonstrating successful build with 'works_great'
struct works_great // No need for BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT - whoopee!
                   // But why - even given the constructor??
{
    intermediate i;
    works_great() = default;
    works_great(intermediate i) : i{i} {}
};

// Not required for 'works_great' - constructors work just fine
//BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(works_great, v)

struct parser : qi::grammar<It, works_great()>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(works_great)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        intermediate = qi::string("test") | qi::int_;

        // rhs should have attribute of type 'variant',
        // matching the constructor
        works_great = '{' >> intermediate >> '}';
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, intermediate()>  intermediate;
    qi::rule<It, works_great()>   works_great;
};

int main()
{
    // The following all compiles/builds just fine
    // (I don't care about the actual runtime results).
    static const parser p;
    works_great wg;
    std::string const data {"{test}"};
    auto f(begin(data)), l(end(data));
    qi::parse(f,l,p,wg);
}
```

**EXAMPLE 2: Vector**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

// We need BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT for this one, but not for the above.
// Constructors don't help. Only difference seems to be
// the vector (rather than variant).
struct not_so_much // not so much - unless BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT is used
{
    std::vector<int> s;

    // Constructors do not help here
    //not_so_much() = default;
    //not_so_much(std::vector<int> s) : s{std::move(s)} {}
};

// Required for 'not_so_much' - constructors don't work
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(not_so_much, s)

// Simple parser demonstrating successful build with 'not_so_much' -
// but only when BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT is used.
struct parser : qi::grammar<It, not_so_much()>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(not_so_much)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        // Note: I know that 'eps' is required, below, to compile the 
        // single-member struct successfully

        // rhs should have attribute of type 'vector<int>',
        // matching the constructor as well...
        // but it doesn't work.
        not_so_much = eps >> (qi::int_ % "|");
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, not_so_much()> not_so_much;
};

int main()
{
    // The following all compiles/builds just fine
    static const parser p;
    not_so_much nm;
    std::string const data {"5|9|16"};
    auto f(begin(data)), l(end(data));
    qi::parse(f,l,p,nm);
}
```

Comment: Are you using MSVC? That stuff shouldn't compile given how you clash the member name `not_so_much` with the typename.

Comment: I was playing around with leaving the names the same as a matter of tangential interest and it did compile on Clang C++2A.  I admit I don't usually do that, and now I wonder if it's clearly legal C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is twofold:

- the attribute is not a container
- the default constructor allows for implicit conversion of synthesized attribute to exposed attribute

The latter difference, you have noticed. The first: not so much.

---

The really principled answer is:

> Qi Attribute Propagation is a heuristic machine.
>
> Sadly, few things optimize for performance (X3 does a lot better). One of the *key areas* that is an exception is the incremental parsing into containers (even across multiple rules)¹.
>
> This makes a lot of sense (since even e.g. building strings character-by-character would be extremely slow...). But it does lead to surprises (eg. [boost::spirit::qi duplicate parsing on the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869978/boostspiritqi-duplicate-parsing-on-the-output/13875183#13875183), [Understanding Boost.spirit's string parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959270/understanding-boost-spirits-string-parser/21960981#21960981))
>
> ¹ (actually also non-containers, but I digress. I don't think it comes into to play without semantic actions)

#### Some Unnecessary Gymnastics

You can actually change the timings at which the attribute propagations fire a bit, and do without the adaptation, though I'd advise against it: just adapting is much more consistent and self-descriptive:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0dafdf40f112a00)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast {
    using vec = std::vector<int>;
    struct not_so_much {
        vec s;

        not_so_much() = default;
        not_so_much(vec s) : s(std::move(s)) {}
    };
}

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
typedef qi::rule<It, Ast::not_so_much()> Parser;

template <typename Expr> void do_test(Expr const& expression) {
    Parser const p = expression;
    Ast::not_so_much nm;

    std::string const data {"5|9|16"};
    It f = begin(data), l = end(data);

    if (qi::parse(f,l,p,nm)) {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << nm.s.size() << " elements: ";
        copy(nm.s.begin(), nm.s.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f != l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}

int main() {
    using namespace qi;
    do_test(attr_cast<Ast::not_so_much, Ast::vec>(int_ % '|'));
    do_test(attr_cast<Ast::not_so_much>(int_ % '|'));

    do_test(as<Ast::vec>()[int_ % '|']);
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed 3 elements: 5 9 16 
Parsed 3 elements: 5 9 16 
Parsed 3 elements: 5 9 16
```

Comment: Added a bit of more generic background.

Comment: Sehe - just want to thank you not only for this dedicated answer, but for all your answers and contributions.  I'm sure I'm not the only one who is grateful and inspired by the time and effort you clearly put in.